# Disable Case Transfer Notification Issue

Tags: email, case

Whenever a case owner is changed, we get the following email notification from `noreply@salesforce.com`.

```
Subject : Case transferred to you

Body : Case XXXXX  has been assigned to you. Please click on the link below to view the record.

https://salesforce url
```

We really do not want this email notification but we are at a loss to understand how to stop it.

I went through some of the related posts here and checked our settings based on the inputs given in those posts but we are still not able to figure out.

This is for straightforward case creation (i.e not via email to case or anything like that)

Our support setting's email notification options looks fine

```
Notify Default Case Owner : FALSE

Notify Case Owner of New Case Comments : FALSE

Notify Case Owners when Case Ownership Changes : FALSE
```

We do not have case assignment rules nor any workflow rules/alerts/flows etc that does this email notification.

Is there any way to turn it off ?

The strange thing is it started appearing in our sandbox (CS57)  only in the last 2 days or so

https://status.salesforce.com/instances/CS57

Any ideas as to where else I can look ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seem to be bug with salesforce, kindly review KI details [here](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000IXfuQAG&_ga=2.230225756.1171608360.1660973808-261753318.1620926533).

Also check below settings.

- Support Settings - Notify Case Owners when Case Ownership Changes
  should be unchecked.
- Email Alert: The process builder is set up to only email in certain
  situations, and it uses a custom template.
- The "Send Notification Email" is set to default off once transfer case to queue/users.

Answer (score 0):

The same can occur for Orgs that didn't configure a 'Default No-Reply' address from the Organization-Wide Addresses page in Setup, after enabling this release update or after the release enforcement:

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_case_email_notification_owa.htm&release=244&type=5

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.email_default_no_reply.htm&type=5

KI: https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000gAwgAAAS/case-transferred-to-you-email-is-sent-after-enabling-use-a-default-no-reply-address-as-system-address-for-case-email-notifications-unexpectedly

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thank you @identigral :)
Maybe it was not completely clear, but I think I did summarise the essential in the first paragraph: the solution may be the configuration of a 'Default No-Reply' Address in Set Up > Organization-Wide Addresses.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue where in I was not able to stop the standard case assignment notification.
But based on above comment by Maria I was able to fix the issue.

To stop emails, if we don't want system to send auto email then "unticking" Send Emails by System Address field needs to be ticked in Support Settings.

If we want to don't want standard email template to be sent to the user then we must configure Default No Reply email address in "Organization Wide Addresses" in setup.

I found a good blog which explains how case assignment emails are sent:
https://www.simplysfdc.com/2021/02/salesforce-email-sent-related-to-case.html